# Regarding Derrida's "Aporias" and "waiting for the other"

Tags: derrida

I'm a newcomer to philosophy, I've been recently introduced by the vector of an English course.

In studying various works, I'm having particular difficulty with the following statement from Derrida's *Aporias: Dying—Awaiting (One Another at) the "Limits of Truth", pages 65 and 66*, which appears, in quoted form, in some of our study material:

> In order to wait for the other at this meeting place, one must, on the
>   contrary, arrive there late, not early.

I've tried to uncover the meaning here, but I'm struggling to make sense of what this is saying. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain (in the simplest terms possible) what this is about.

Comment: Would you have a page number for the Derrida quote? This would just help someone find the quote if they have a paper copy. I do see it on Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/GiftDeath.TheJacquesDerrida/page/n1 Welcome to this SE!

Comment: I realize that the quote comes from study material so you wouldn't know where it is in the original. You might ask this from your instructor. I couldn't find the quote in the translation on Internet Archive. Perhaps others would be able to. Hopefully someone has an answer.

Comment: Hello Frank, thank you for replying. My apologies; I was led to believe that the quoted portion appeared originally in _The Gift of Death_, but I must belatedly correct this. The material we're studying is from Derrida's later lecture-cum-essay _Aporias: Dying—Awaiting (One Another at) the "Limits of Truth"_, specifically pages 65 and 66

Comment: I edited the incorrect reference, you can of course revert or continue editing by using the 'edit' button at the bottom of the post. And welcome!

Comment: **christo183** Thank you for doing that for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In order to wait for the other at this meeting place, one must, on the contrary, arrive there late, not early.

This is tied into the [French pronominal verb](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-verb-conjugation/french-pronominal-verbs-french-reflexive-reciprocal-verbs-a-summary), *s'attendre* (to expect) which Derrida is making much of here.

"one expects it" - "*on s'y attend*" - one self-awaits it

One awaits one's late self : one expects death.

Further, one's manifest non-existence (death) can only arrive *after* one's manifest existence has unwound.  Hence the "impossible simultaneity" of the rendezvous. (page 65)

Comment: Thank you **Chris**, that's very helpful. Permit me to attempt to recast this segment according to my limited and rather fey understanding of things. First, a summary. EDIT: I'll have to split this into more than one comment due to the character limit, I hope the posts will appear in "oldest first" order.

On page 64 Derrida says: "_One simply awaits oneself: I await myself, and nothing else; I myself await myself in myself; and this is the most identifiable and most identifying self-relation, i.e., the ego's memory or promise of itself_".

Comment: Skipping ahead to page 65 he states: "_awaiting oneself... can have a notable relation to death (it is there, and maybe only there, that one ultimately awaits oneself or expects, that one expects that; and it is only there that the awaiting oneself may be no other than the expecting the other, or that the other may arrive)_"

A little further down he says: "_we can wait for each other ... when the waiting for each other is related to death, to the borders of death ... the one is waiting for the other there_"

Comment: And then towards the bottom of page 65 and leading into 66 he says: "_Both the one and the other never arrive together at this rendezvous, and the one who waits for the other there, at this border, is not he who arrives there first or she who gets there first. In order to wait for the other at this meeting place, one must, on the contrary, arrive there late, not early._"

Taking these statements together, along with the information you have provided, I'm interpreting this as follow:

Comment: I have an expectation of my future death. However, on this side of "the borders of death" (p.65) - while I am alive - I can not enter into a state of "being" dead. I can only cross this border after the event of my death has taken place, which concomitantly means that my life will already have ended.

Comment: So (while living) I cannot "arrive early" into this state of being dead, I can only come to this state "late" after the "unwinding of my manifest existence" - to appropriate your term.
More ambiguously, it is not I, in the present, who await myself at these borders, but rather the future-state me, the post-death-event me who I have yet to become.

Comment: @AMarch Sounds about right, but as Derrida says "the untranslatability of the idiom" (page 64) complicates what is probably clearer in French.

Comment: @AMarch I asked a professional linguist about this verb, s’attendre. She said ‘se’ is used more as an intensifier on some verbs, (in Spanish also). So to expect is an intensification of to await. Derrida’s use of the reflexive sense: to self-await, is somewhat playing around with language.

Comment: That's very insightful, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to search the portion on the Internet; but couldn't.  So the only statement with me is the quote you posted from that book.  I think that is about a 'bizarre' meeting place.  So, to guess the meaning, please refer the preceding statements and try to understand whether there things work in the reverse order...or the person who reached there early loses something (or gets less time) and the person who reached there late gains something (or gets more time). Whatever it is this will help you to reach close to the meaning. So I think this might help you to understand the meaning.

Comment: Thank you **SonOfThought**, I made the task unnecessarily difficult by giving the wrong essay title, and including an inadequately short context segment, but I'm very grateful for your efforts and appreciate the suggestion.